# type_info doesn't account for cv qualifiers: is this right?

Tags: c++, g++, constants, volatile, rtti

Is it the correct behaviour or is it a quirk of g++4.5 that this code prints 1?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    struct A{};
    cout<<(typeid(A)==typeid(const A)&&typeid(A)==typeid(const volatile A)&&typeid(A)==typeid(volatile A));
}
```

I thought that types differing for cv-qualifiers were threated as very distinct types, even though less cv-qualified types could be implicitly cast to more cv-qualified types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typeid` ignores cv qualifiers, as per the C++ standard (taken from §5.2.8 from ISO/IEC 14882:2003) :

> The top-level cv-qualifiers of the lvalue expression or the type-id that is the operand of typeid are always
>   ignored. [Example:

```
class D { ... };
D d1;
const D d2;

typeid(d1) == typeid(d2);       // yields true
typeid(D) == typeid(const D);   // yields true
typeid(D) == typeid(d2);        // yields true
typeid(D) == typeid(const D&);  // yields true
```

> —end example]

So, the result you're seeing is expected.

Comment: Here is a "Gotcha" concerning comparing results of two typeid operators. That is, quote "There is no guarantee that the same std::type_info instance will be referred to by all evaluations of the typeid expression on the same type, although std::type_info::hash_code of those type_info objects would be identical, as would be their std::type_index." typeid(d1) == typeid(d2) is not guaranteed.

Comment: @JohnZ.Li : `std::type_info` has an `operator==` defined that _Returns true if the two values describe the same type_.

Comment: I misunderstood the wording of the standard, Sander De Dycker is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As @SanderDeDycker mentioned cv qualifiers are ignored. But not for pointers!

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
    int bar = 1;
    const int cbar = 10;
    volatile int vbar = 10;
    const volatile int cvbar = 1000;
    int &rbar = bar;
    const int &crbar = bar;
    volatile int &vrbar = bar;
    const volatile int &cvrbar = bar;
    int *pbar = &bar;
    const int *cpbar = &bar;
    volatile int *vpbar = &bar;
    const volatile int *cvpbar = &bar;
    const volatile int * const cvpcbar = &bar;
    const volatile int * const volatile cvpcvbar = &bar;
    int&& rrbar = 894354;
    const int&& rrcbar = 894354;

    std::cout << typeid(bar).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(cbar).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(vbar).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(cvbar).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(rbar).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(crbar).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(vrbar).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(cvrbar).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(pbar).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(cpbar).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(vpbar).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(cvpbar).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(cvpcbar).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(cvpcvbar).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(rrbar).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(rrcbar).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}
```

*Output*

```
int
int
int
int
int
int
int
int
int * __ptr64
int const * __ptr64
int volatile * __ptr64
int const volatile * __ptr64
int const volatile * __ptr64
int const volatile * __ptr64
int
int
```

As you can see cv qualifiers are not ignored in the 5 cases involving pointers. Output is the same for MSVS or g++ and C++11, C++14, C++17.

Comment: It is top-level cv qualifiers that are ignored (as explained by Sander's answer)